# JPA: How to cascade modification of one field to reflect another?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have the following Schema:

```
@Entity
public class A{
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dest",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<C> myDest; //Owns these

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<C> myParents; //can be reached from these 

@ManyToMany
private Collection<B> myOwnB;;
}


@Entity
public class B{
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "forB",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<C> associatedC;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "myOwnB")
private Collection<A> associatedA;
}


@Entity
public class C{
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "myDest")
@ManyToOne
private A dest;

@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "myParents")
@ManyToOne
private A owner;

@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "associatedC")
@ManyToOne
private B forB;
}
```

Here, if I delete a record of A or B, all the associated Cs get deleted. Perfect.

So my problem is this:
If I delete a reference of B from A (in that ManyToMany relation), I need all the Cs deleted as well for that A and B. (All Cs where forB=removedB and owner=sourceA). I have now written a similar query and it works fine now that I explicitly execute in my EJB. Is there a workaround or a annotation saying that a record of C gets deleted if one of the attributes(column) become null?

Comment: I believe there is no such annotation as you ask. With a little refactoring though, you could replace the `@ManyToMany` relationship between A-B with the C entity itself. If I understand well, the "many As to many Bs" relationship is a relationship with properties. These properties are kept in the entity C, that is related with A and B. You could "break" the "many As to many Bs" relationship to "one As to many Cs *AND* one B to many Cs". Then un-relating an A with a B means deleting the C entity, which is what you want because the C *IS* the reference between A and B.

Comment: Even if I loosen up the relationship to something like A<-->C<-->B, removing a reference of C from A or B wouldn't delete the record, right? I believe there is no annotation, like you mentioned, and I should probably use @NotNull to ensure consistency.

Comment: Actually, if you keep the relationship A<-->C as `@OneToMany(..., orphanRemoval = true) Collection<C> myDest;`, removing a `C` from the `myDest` collection should remove it from the DB because of the `orphanRemoval=true`.